# Каким образом с помощью цикла можно решить задание?

Tags: java

Сумма 10 чисел
Вывести на экран сумму чисел от 1 до 10 построчно (должно быть 10 строк):

```
1
1+2=3
1+2+3=6
1+2+3+4=10
...
```

**Пример** вывода:

```
1
3
6
10
```

Вот пример кода, не знаю, что делать дальше...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int a = 1; a <= 10; a++){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите части кода, в которых вы пытались решить данную задачу.

Comment: а с чем у вас возникли проблемы? предоставьте кусок кода. Тут не принято решать за человека, тут принято помогать.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       for(int a=1;a<=10;a++){
           System.out.println(a);
       }

    }

Comment: 1,3,6,10 и по наростающей

Comment: я не понимаю как задать плавающую  разницу

Comment: @user212022 создаете внутри первого цикла переменную sum =0, а также создаете внутри него же еще один цикл от j= 0 до j<= i и складываете в переменную суммы элементов массива с индексом j

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно без второго цикла обойтись

Comment: @Denis да наверное. Я почему-то решил что дан массив с различными числами размером 10 и имелся в виду пробег от 1 до 10 элемента, а не просто от 1 до 10) и что надо прям так и выводить `1+2=3
1+2+3=6
1+2+3+4`.....а для этого нужно было бы два цикла.... спать надо больше мне, видимо........ а вам не стоит делать задачки за других.... это неправильно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так задачка не с нуля - он добавил кусок кода, дальше не смог написать из-за незнания/нехватки аналитических способностей или тоже мало спал) мы попросили кусок кода, он предоставил - мы помогли, это правильно.

Comment: @Denis можо было предоставить алгоритм действий ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне не жалко пояснить подробнее, чтобы человек лучше понял)

Comment: спасибо)ыфвапевфапывап

Answer (score 3):

Вам достаточно запоминать сумму и каждый раз к ней прибавлять следующее число:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

**Вывод**: http://ideone.com/hhU29F

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое я тож чот так думал ток ставил эту переменную sum в блоке  for и  с каждым циклом возвращалось первоначальнное значение

Comment: терь буду знать

Comment: @user212022 если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галочкой как правильный для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на этот вопрос.